# Can't create and attach an AWS IoT Policy to my certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot

I'm following seemingly simple [instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/secure-communication.html) on setting up Amazon IOT, and came to halt when trying to create policy.

Documentation says to create a policy with a sample JSON provided. I am following the instructions exactly:

I created a txt file called myTestPolicy.txt like this:

```
{

    "Version": "2016-3-3", 
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action":["iot:*"],
        "Resource": ["*"]
    }]
}
```

placed in the local folder, but when I run the command:

**aws iot create-policy --policy-name "PubSubToAnyTopic" --policy-document file://myTestPolicy.txt**

I get an error:

> *A client error (MalformedPolicyException) occurred when calling the CreatePolicy operation: Policy document is Malformed*

Totally stuck, googling yields no answers, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I opened a support ticket (paid) with Amazon, and tech confirmed that there is a bug in the documentation and/or the tools. He opened a ticket with engineering.

In the meantime, I was able to do this from AWS Dashboard (the IoT web UI allows you to create a policy and also do the other tasks that the (dysfunctional) CLI documentation is trying to guide you through.

Answer (score 0):

The version you selected is not recognized. If you try with "2012-10-17" it works fine (you can select either "2008-10-17" or "2012-10-17").

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17", 
    "Statement": [{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action":["iot:*"],
        "Resource": ["*"]
    }]
}
```